# Setting ContextMenu on SetOnLongClickListener

Tags: android, button, contextmenu, onlongclicklistener

How can I set my app to show Context Menu on Long Click Listener?
I want it when I click to play sound, and on long click to show menu with some options and buttons, on 1 same button.
So I want o normal click to play sound, on long click to show menu with some buttons which I can use to set as ringtone and other stuff.

```
mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hekler);

ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


    if (mp2.isPlaying()){
        mp2.pause();
        mp2.seekTo(0);
    }

    else{
        mp.start();
    }

}

});

btn1.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {       
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show a context menu on long click, you should call `registerForContextMenu(View)` for view that is clicked.

You should also override `onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu, View, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo)`

You not need `setOnLongClickListener`. If you need it for some other reason, it should return false.

In your code:

```
ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
registerForContextMenu(btn1);

btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    -------------
    -------------

}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_context_menu, menu);
}
```

To handle the context menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.contextItem1:
            //Do what you want
        return true;

        case R.id.contextItem2:
            //Do what you want
        return true;

        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```